# How do max-age, min-fresh and max-stale HTTP headers work from client (request headers) using Express js as server?

Tags: node.js, express, caching, http-headers, cache-control

I have a server with Express js in Node js, I send the following from the server the `Cache-Control` with the values `max-age=50`, (I want it to have 50 seconds of freshness, this value is only for testing):

```js
server.get('/data', (_, res) => {
    res.set('Cache-Control', 'max-age=50');
    res.json({
        msg: 'Hola',
    });
});
```

From the client I assign max-stale or min-fresh or max-age, but it doesn't seem to have an effect on the cache behavior:

```js
document.getElementById('btn-get-data').addEventListener('click', () => {
    fetch('http://localhost:4000/data', {
        headers: {
            'Cache-Control': 'max-stale=50',// <-- I also tried max-age and min-fresh
        },
    })
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then((json) => {
            console.log(json);
        })
        .catch((error) => console.log(error));
});
```

For example, I simulate that the client loses the internet connection (offline), the cache is still fresh, since I allocate 50 seconds, but when the cache expires, it does not continue to use or serve the obsolete cache even though I specify that it will use `max-stale=50` from the client.

[image]

I tried max-age and min-fresh but I haven't seen any caching behavior. the documentation says:

> **max-age**
> Indicates that the client is willing to accept a response whose age is no greater than the specified time in seconds. Unless max- stale directive is also included, the client is not willing to accept a stale response.
> **min-fresh**
> Indicates that the client is willing to accept a response whose freshness lifetime is no less than its current age plus the specified time in seconds. That is, the client wants a response that will still be fresh for at least the specified number of seconds.
> **max-stale**
> Indicates that the client is willing to accept a response that has exceeded its expiration time. If max-stale is assigned a value, then the client is willing to accept a response that has exceeded its expiration time by no more than the specified number of seconds. If no value is assigned to max-stale, then the client is willing to accept a stale response of any age.

But it doesn't work. How do these three headers work from the client? Am I misunderstanding? Can someone explain this headings with simple or verbose words and how to assign them from the client?

Answer (score 0):

Try using 'res.setHeader' and make sure to include the 'public' directive.

```
res.setHeader("Cache-Control", "public, max-age=50");
```

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/node-js-response-setheader-method/

> Parameters: This property accepts a single parameter as mentioned
> above and described below:
>
> - name : It accepts the name of the header and it is case-insensitive.
> - value : It can accept any values like objects, string, integer, Array, etc.
>
> Return Value: It does not return any value, instead sets a header

Comment: I am without a computer this week, I can barely, I will do tests and let you know, thanks for now :)

Answer (score 0):

You're using [`max-stale`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7234#section-5.2.1.2) correctly here:

> If max-stale is assigned a value, then the client is
> willing to accept a response that has exceeded its freshness lifetime
> by no more than the specified number of seconds.

Your browser's cache is private, so you shouldn't need to put a `public` directive for it to be used.

However, you should confirm that the browser you're using supports these headers. For example, [back in 2017](https://www.mnot.net/blog/2017/03/16/browser-caching#request-cache-control):

> Chrome only supports `max-age=0` in requests, and only with the value 0. It does not support `min-fresh` or `max-stale`.

Compare with:

> Of the tested browsers, Firefox supports `max-age`, `max-stale` and `min-fresh` in requests, both with a simple freshness lifetime, and when the `Age` header is present.